# Wordpress: Images appear blurry on newer macbook with higher density pixels

Tags: wordpress

I built a Wordpress site with stock and own images. Up to a certain quality of screen, everything looks fine, but on screens with high retina display like the newer macbook pro, they show blurry.

I have already installed a plugin called WP Retina 2X, and it seems that the images where fixed on a few devices, however, not on the latest macbook.

If you have a retina display device, the site in question is: www.binarymango.com/augmented-reality

Is there any tip as to how I can correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Please add this plugin in your website "https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-retina-2x/".

Comment: Thanks poonam. As I mention on the question, I am already using this plugin